# Android - issue in getting runtime permission

Tags: java, android

In my app am getting run time permission.
Here is how am getting request

```
ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(IntroductionSlider.this,String[]{ Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION,Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE},REQUEST_CODE);
```

Here is how am getting result

```
@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {


    boolean flag=false;
    if(requestCode == REQUEST_CODE){

        if(grantResults.length>0){
            if(grantResults[0]==PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && grantResults[1]==PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && grantResults[2]==PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
                flag=true;
            }
        }

        if(flag){
            Toast.makeText(IntroductionSlider.this,"Granted",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            startActivity(new Intent(IntroductionSlider.this,oneTimeValidation.class));
            finish();
        }else {


            Toast.makeText(IntroductionSlider.this,"Goto to setting->Apps->My market->Permissions grant all permissions to proceed",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
        return;
    }

}
```

My problem is eventhough i **deny** some permissions in runtime.i am getting the toast **"Granted"** ie.in if block. do no why this happens
Can anyone help me please.

Answer (score 1):

Set boolean for every permission & check , If all permission allows than only toast will show permission granted otherwise permission denied. Its workable code I already used this on my app.

Reference :https://www.android-examples.com/request-check-multiple-runtime-permissions-android-marshmallow/

Use below code,

```
@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String permissions[], int[] grantResults) {
    switch (requestCode) {

        case RequestPermissionCode:

            if (grantResults.length > 0) {

                boolean CameraPermission = grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED;
                boolean ReadContactsPermission = grantResults[1] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED;
                boolean ReadPhoneStatePermission = grantResults[2] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED;

                if (CameraPermission && ReadContactsPermission && ReadPhoneStatePermission) {

                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Permission Granted", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
                else {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Permission Denied",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                }
            }

            break;
    }
}
```

Comment: just a suggestion, variables should be camel case and should not start with caps

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion @RohanKandwal

Answer (score 0):

I think you should check this library for best practice, it'll save your time and also easy to manage.
 https://www.androidhive.info/2017/12/android-easy-runtime-permissions-with-dexter/